# What topics should my questions cover on Computational Science?

Tags: discussion

From what I've seen [on Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320/shall-we-unite-computational-science-proposals), this site is supposed to be a more general-purpose Q/A place than most of the others StackExchange sites.

I'm a bit confused about what kind of questions I should ask here since it seems to cover a lot of ground, and I want to make sure I'm in the right place for the following:

- Computer vision
- Machine learning
- AI

More generally, if this is supposed to combine most of the computational science proposals, why are some sites for example about Computer Vision still in commit phase? There seems to be a certain overlap of sites where some questions can be asked. Take computer vision for example: it can fit on SO, but also on DSP, soon on Computer Vision, and also (I think) here, should I just post my question on all 4?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

We try to think of the sites as overlapping, and the questions that go to our community tend to be answered by computational scientists with experience in algorithms, hardware, and software tools, as opposed to experts in particular domains.  You should, if possible, try to target the question to the *best* community to answer your question, even though multiple communities may be able to help.  I'm in favor of cross-posting only when the question doesn't seem to have gotten a strong response or answer in the first community you asked it in.

If you can put together a particular question, I'm happy to give you my opinion on where it should go.  In general, we are pretty welcoming here for any well-thought out questions that discuss computational or numerical algorithms, their performance on computers, and scientific computing in general.